# Memory usage issue in WordPress 3.x

Tags: memory

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ... bytes) in wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line ...
```

1. Plugins like Super-cashe & Total-cashe don't help.
2. Reducing the number of wordpress plugins and widgets used gives minimal effect.

Can anyone offer solution (except asking my hoster for more memory) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the memory for PHP and Wordpress by editing the memory_limit line in your php.ini (if you have access to it) to 64M:

`memory_limit = 64M;`

If no php.ini, or add this line at the top of .htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 64M`

If that doesn't work, add this line near the top of your wp-config.php file (right after the opening  `<?php` )

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

And ask your web host.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on my WP site, I think it was actually a plugin causing a problem, quite possibly a caching one...

Couple of questions:

What is it you are trying to do when the error appears?

What plugins do you have active?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into your wp config:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```